# why the results of fortran mkl-fftw3 and matlab are not aligned?

Tags: matlab, fortran, fft, fftw, intel-mkl

I just want to convert my code from matlab to fortran. So I used the mkl-fftw3 library to complete the FFT computation. But during my test, the position of mkl-fftw3 results does not align with matlab results, it might seems like it's the reverse of matlab results.

Is there anyway to transform the fortran results to align with the matlab results?

In fortran I just wrote

```
      double complex t_in(5),t_out(5)
      integer*8 plan
      t_in = dcmplx([1:5])
      call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(plan,5,t_in,t_out,FFTW_RODFT00,FFTW_EST
 1  IMATE)
      call dfftw_execute_dft(plan, t_in, t_out)
      call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan)
      PRINT *,t_out
```

As you want, I change it to FFTW_FORWARD

```
      call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(plan,5,t_in,t_out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_EST
 1  IMATE)
```

I also calculated the backward with t_out as the input

In matlab

```
      fft([1:5])
```

FORTRAN:

(15.0000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000) (-2.50000000000000,-3.44095480117793)
 (-2.50000000000000,-0.812299240582266) (-2.50000000000000,0.812299240582266)
 (-2.50000000000000,3.44095480117793)

FFTW_FORWARD_FORTRAN:
 (15.0000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000) (-2.50000000000000,-3.44095480117793)
 (-2.50000000000000,-0.812299240582266) (-2.50000000000000,0.812299240582266)
 (-2.50000000000000,3.44095480117793)

FFTW_BACKWARD_FORTRAN:

(5,0) (25,0) (20,0) (15,0) (10,0)

MATLAB:

15.0000 + 0.0000i  -2.5000 + 3.4410i  -2.5000 + 0.8123i  -2.5000 - 0.8123i  -2.5000 - 3.4410i

Comment: Why are you using `FFTW_RODFT00` (`DST-I`) ?

Comment: In fact this option does not matter, though I used FFTW_FORWARD it was still the same result

Comment: And what happens if you use FFTW_BACKWARD? And you have included in you code the appropriate lines to make sure it has access to the values required for things like FFTW_ESTIMATE? If so please include it in the code above, it's important!

Comment: Looks a bit strange to me because the results agree between FFTW_FORWARD and Matlab above on my computer (with gfortran8 + FFTW3). Maybe useful to create an MCVE (a compilable, stand-alone example) with a compiler option used...? Also the definition of complex FFT here: [matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) (at the bottom of the page) and [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029)

Comment: So the reason might be the IDE? I just used the vs2017, ivf2019 and the integrated mkl option.

Comment: It might be so, but I cannot say for sure... (so hope someone familiar with VS will help). Also make sure that  "implicit none" and "include 'fftw3.f' are given in the current scope (so that FFTW_FORWARD etc are given the meaningful values).

Comment: In fact I tried to just use the FFTW3 library not the MKL-FFTW3 , the result is right,